# Android - drawing to the screen for a board game?

Tags: android, graphics2d, ondraw

I am attempting to implement a board game for Android, and I was wanting to get some opinions on a good strategy for drawing to the screen.  The board consists of 30 or so rooms (rectangles) with doors (lines), and then small bitmaps for the player tokens.  I was thinking I could save all of the points to be drawn for rectangles/lines in a ArrayList, and do the actual drawing of onDraw method of a View, using the points saved in the lists.

Does this seem like a reasonable approach for a mostly static board for a board game?

Comment: If your game is "mostly static" than yes, it's a good way to do so.

Comment: The "mostly static" part is pretty key. Do you expect you'll have any animation?